# Implementation of a 24 hour variable resistive load fluctuation

Tags: resistors, resistance, load, digital-potentiometer

I am implementing a DC microgrid with a variable resistive load variation of 24-hours, based on a load profile.

I have implemented it in MATLAB through a variable resistor and a 1-D block to provide the profile to the variable resistor as in [1].

Doed anyone know how the hardware of it can be implemented practically in a laboratory, as I am now trying to build the hardware implementation of the circuit.

[implementation of variable resistive load profile in MATLAB][1]][1]

Comment: MATLAB/Python script and a programmable DC load comes to mind.

Comment: This question is a bit broad, what are the intended voltages, currents and number of load nodes?

Comment: Thank you very much,

Comment: The design is a 48V DC microgrid with three fluctuated load profiles. I have implemented this in MATLAB through a variable resistance taking the signal from a 1-D block (as a 24 hour load profile). And now, I wanted to implement the hardware.

Comment: Can you explain more about how to use the DC programmable load with MATLAB script? I know that programmable DC load is used for battery testing, or another purpose. But have no idea about how to use it with a MATLAB script to attain a resistive load fluctuation profile.